# "Layout or its parent is useless". How to avoid this?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have 2 bordered textviews to center vertically and horizontally, side by side as it is shown in the following image:

[image]

On top of each of these 2 textviews, I have to add a 'T' textview on the bottom left and a unit on the bottom right ('uV/m').  To do this I end up with the following layout xml code:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_small_rectancle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/drv3lite_small_rectangle_height"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <!-- Small rectangles. Defines the whole width -->
    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" 
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <!-- Small rectangle (left) -->
        <RelativeLayout 
            android:layout_width="@dimen/drv3lite_small_rectangle_width"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblValueLTE"
                android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/color_green"
                android:textSize="@dimen/drv3lite_small_rectangle_text_size"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="1317" 
                android:enabled="true"
                android:background="@drawable/selector_drv3lite_round_corners_lte"/>

            <!-- Tag indicator -->          
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblTagLTE"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:gravity="start" 
                android:layout_marginLeft="5sp" 
                android:layout_marginStart="5sp"    
                android:textColor="@color/color_green"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="T" />

            <!-- Units -->          
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblUnitsLTE"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:layout_marginRight="5sp"    
                android:layout_marginEnd="5sp"  
                android:textColor="@color/color_green"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="&#181;V/m" />                                     
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <!-- Small rectangles. Defines the whole width -->
    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <!-- Small rectangle (right) -->                        
        <RelativeLayout 
            android:layout_width="@dimen/drv3lite_small_rectangle_width"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblValueMid"
                android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/color_orange"
                android:textSize="@dimen/drv3lite_small_rectangle_text_size" 
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="145" 
                android:enabled="true"
               android:background="@drawable/selector_drv3lite_round_corners_mid"/>

            <!-- Tag indicator -->          
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblTagMid"
                android:layout_width="30sp" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:gravity="start" 
                android:layout_marginLeft="5sp" 
                android:layout_marginStart="5sp"    
                android:textColor="@color/color_orange"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="T" />

            <!-- Units -->          
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblUnitsMid"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:layout_marginRight="5sp"    
                android:layout_marginEnd="5sp"  
                android:textColor="@color/color_orange"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="&#181;V/m" />
        </RelativeLayout>               
    </RelativeLayout>               
</LinearLayout>
```

So:

- First level: layout_small_rectangle allows me to center vertically;
- Second level: the 2 RelativeLayout with weight of 1 allows me to distribute evenly the 2 textviews with borders horizontally;
- Third level: relative layout that allows me to align to the left/right the 'T' and 'UV/m' textviews inside the bordered textview;

My question: is it possible to avoid the IDE warning saying that 'a layout is useless', caused by the successive RelativeLayout of level 2 and 3?

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the two parent RelativeLayouts and apply weights to the children to get the same effect.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_small_rectancle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

<!-- Small rectangles. Defines the whole width -->

<!-- Small rectangle (left) -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblValueLTE"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="1317"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <!-- Tag indicator -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblTagLTE"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5sp"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:text="T"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <!-- Units -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblUnitsLTE"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5sp"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:text="&#181;V/m"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>
<!-- Small rectangles. Defines the whole width -->

<!-- Small rectangle (right) -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblValueMid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="145"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <!-- Tag indicator -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblTagMid"
        android:layout_width="30sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5sp"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:text="T"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <!-- Units -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblUnitsMid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5sp"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:text="&#181;V/m"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I tried your solution and it doesn't work since the 2 textviews rectangles not touch each other in the middle of the screen.  Somewhere, I guess you need to specify their width (drv3lite_small_rectangle_width)...

Comment: ...I mean "**now** touch each other..."

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layout_small_rectancle"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<!-- Small rectangles. Defines the whole width -->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"></LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- Small rectangle (left) -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblValueLTE"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:enabled="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="1317"
                android:textColor="#66CC33"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"></TextView>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <!-- Tag indicator -->
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblTagLTE"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
                android:layout_marginStart="5sp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:gravity="start"
                android:text="T"
                android:textColor="#66CC33"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <!-- Units -->
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblUnitsLTE"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5sp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5sp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="&#181;V/m"
                android:textColor="#66CC33"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- Small rectangles. Defines the whole width -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"></LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:background="@drawable/button_bg_next"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- Small rectangle (left) -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblValueLTEy"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:enabled="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="145"
                android:textColor="#FF7E00"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"></TextView>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <!-- Tag indicator -->
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblTagLTEw"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
                android:layout_marginStart="5sp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:gravity="start"
                android:text="T"
                android:textColor="#FF7E00"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <!-- Units -->
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblUnitsLTEg"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5sp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5sp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="&#181;V/m"
                android:textColor="#FF7E00"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
   </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
```

button_bg.xml(in drawable folder)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">

<corners android:radius="5dip" />
<solid android:color="#fff" />
<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="#66CC33" />

</shape>
```

button_bg_next(in drawable folder)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">

<corners android:radius="5dip" />
<solid android:color="#fff" />
<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="#FF7E00" />

</shape>
```

Comment: I still got a useless view warning with this, releated to your 2 empty linearLayouts (_"This LinearLayout view is useless (no children, no background, no id, no style"_)) so it doesn't solve my problem...

Comment: I have used this in my project and its working fine. Strange its not working for you.